# Change TextView Array properties in ViewHolder

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, textview

I am trying to change properties of my Textview Array which I am inserting into a RecyclerView. I want negative numbers to be red and positive green. Pretty simple.

Declaration :   `public TextView[] mDay= new TextView[100];`

Initialization:

```
for(int i=0;i<=99;i++){
mDay[i] = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day_text);
    }
```

Show in Layout :

```
Public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

 //Hier werden die ganzen Daten eingebunden
                holder.mCoin.setText(mDataset[position]);
                holder.mPrice.setText(mDataset2[position]);

               for(int i=0;i<=mDataset4.length-1;i++){
                  if(mDataset4[i].contains("-"))
                  {
                    Log.w("Negativ",mDataset4[i]);
                      holder.mDay[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                      holder.mDay[i].setText(mDataset4[i]);
                  }

               else {
                      Log.w("Positiv",mDataset4[i]);
                      holder.mDay[i].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                      holder.mDay[i].setText(mDataset4[i]);
                  }

               }
```

Only the last data in my Dataset is inserted in the RecyclerView [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvGme.png).

When i insert my Dataset like the other, everything is in the right place

```
 holder.mDay[position].setText(mDataset2[position]);
```

[Obviously there is no color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyyEJ.png)

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Myviewholder :

```
     public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView mCoin;
        public TextView mPrice;
        public TextView mDay;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
//Sachen aus dem Layout zuordnen
            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mCoin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.coin_text);
            mPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price_text);
            mDay = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day_text);
        }
    }
```

My Consturcutor: I have multiple Datasets so I can load different data into different texviews and so on.

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList <String> coin,ArrayList <String> cap,ArrayList <String> price,ArrayList <String> day) {
    mDataset = coin.toArray(new String[coin.size()]);
    mDataset2 = cap.toArray(new String[cap.size()]);
    mDataset3 = price.toArray(new String[price.size()]);
    mDataset4 = day.toArray(new String[day.size()]);
}
```

My onBindViewHolder function : I load my data into my desired textviews and after that I try to change the Textview color based on if its negative or positive

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Hier werden die ganzen Daten eingebunden
        holder.mCoin.setText(mDataset[position]);
        holder.mPrice.setText(mDataset2[position]);


       for(int i=0;i<=mDataset4.length-1;i++){
          if(mDataset4[i].contains("-"))
          {
              Log.w("Negativ",mDataset4[i]);
              holder.mDay.setTextColor(Color.RED);
              holder.mDay.setText(mDataset4[i]);
          }

       else {
              Log.w("Positiv",mDataset4[position]);
              holder.mDay.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
              holder.mDay.setText(mDataset4[position]);
          }

       }


        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String currentValue = mDataset[position];
                Log.d("CardView", "CardView Clicked: " + currentValue);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You will need to post more code to make it easier to come up with an accurate answer for you.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You have 100 `TextView`s in one row of your `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: No, I dont have 100 Textviews. I have only 1 in my CardFragment. I tried declaring it as Array, so i can change the color of each entry. Check the images, maybe they can help you to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you doing this::  "public MyAdapter(ArrayList <String> coin,ArrayList <String> cap,ArrayList <String> price,ArrayList <String> day) {" ?? Are all these `ArrayList` objects the same size?? If not then this  "mDataset[position]" ... "mDataset4[position]"  won't work!  You should create a class with all the values you need to fill your `RecyclerView` with public getters and setters (Standard Java stuff!).

Comment: Yikes.So I have 4 different ArrayLists which I give over to the constructor so I can use that data. This seems to work. One Arraylist for one mDataset. Data and all is showed correctly but its just that I cant change the color for each row .

Comment: I have taken a look at your other question on JSON parsing. I assume you are getting your data from that JSON response. Take a look at my comment in that post. Perhaps I can help you on that issue. That would also set the basis for a cleaner solution with your `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create an Array of `TextView`s. Your `RecyclerView` already has the `TextView` you need. You just need to access it.

Since you did not post all the code need to reconstruct your problem I had to make a few guesses.

Do something like this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mDay;
    public TextView mCoin;
    public TextView mPrice;

    public MyViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        // I am just guessing at the View ids. You need to substitute the right ones
        mDay = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day_text);
        mCoin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.coin_text);
        mPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price_text);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why you have mDataset, mDataset2 and mDataset4?? You passed the RecyclerView an ArrayList (I assume) with the class holding the data you wish to display. It should look something like this

```
private ArrayList<MyDataSet> mDataset;
public EventsRecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyDataSet> data){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDataset = data;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    MyDataSet data = mDataset.get(position);

    holder.mCoin.setText(data.getCoin());
    holder.mPrice.setText(data.getPrice);
    String day = data.getDay();
    holder.mDay.setText(day);

    if(day.contains("-")){
        Log.w("Negativ", day);
        holder.mDay.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else {
        Log.w("Positiv", day);
        holder.mDay.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Now you need to make your `MyDataSet` class with the necessary getters and setters!

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Sadly, it dosent seem to work. Id be glad if you would look at my edit. Cheers mate

Comment: I made one small tweak, but this is what I assume Micheal wants to do too.

Comment: @Sam :: Thanks I didn't catch that error with `mDay[]` (I was writing my answer in a simple text editor since I wasn't working from my developer computer).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is only finding one TextView

```
mDay[i] = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day_text);
```

The `R.id.day_text` needs to be unique for each `i`.

---

**Edit**

With the new code that you added I have a better understanding of what you are doing. But you still seem confused on this section in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= mDataset4.length - 1; i++) {
    if (mDataset4[i].contains("-")) {
        Log.w("Negativ", mDataset4[i]);
        holder.mDay.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.mDay.setText(mDataset4[i]);
    } else {
        Log.w("Positiv", mDataset4[position]);
        holder.mDay.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        holder.mDay.setText(mDataset4[position]);
    }
}
```

There are a few problems:

1. `holder.mDay` refers to only one TextView, but your loop is trying to set four values.  So the first three values are just over written by the last value.

   I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, do you want four different TextViews to display all of `mDataset4`? Then add more TextViews or rows or whatever to display the data the way you want it.

   Or do you only want to display one of the elements in `mDataset4`? Then simply call the appropriate value and remove the entire loop.
2. The `else` clause does the same thing 4 times.  Absolutely nothing changes because you never reference `i`.

Comment: Why is that? I thought using RecyclerView meant only using one Textview. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Yes, that is what a ViewHolder is intended to do if you set it up properly. I assume that your loop is in your ViewHolder constructor, it needs to be fixed for the reason I pointed out above.

Comment: I dont quite understand how to fix it, since I only have one TextView in my Card fragment. The loop is inside MyViewHolder class. Id be glad if you could explain a little further.

Comment: Post the code for the layout in each row and your MyViewHolder constructor. Then let me know.

Comment: `onBindViewHolder()` is intended to be used the way [Barnes' answer is written.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481078/1267661) You should modify your code to match it.

Comment: I really apreciate your effort and ill try to explain the problem agian. So mDataset4 is a String Array which has 100 different values. These values are on the right side of each row. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyyEJ.png) This value is either negative or positive. I want to show all of my values in each of their row in my CardView. I just want that either the text color is red when the value is minus and if the value is green I want it to be green.

Answer (score 0):

First use the answer by sam and then following:
The code you shared is incomplete but still after getting an idea of what you are trying to do you can solve your problem like this:
You can only use position as it holds the current view on screen

```
              if(mDataset4[position]<0)
              {
                Log.w("Negativ",mDataset4[position]);
                  holder.mDay[position].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                  holder.mDay[position].setText(mDataset4[position]);
              }

           else {
                  Log.w("Positiv",mDataset4[position]);
                  holder.mDay[position].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                  holder.mDay[position].setText(mDataset4[position]);
              }
```